# SQL Query to get related value from additional join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a simple Select statement that returns data from 2 MySQL tables which is working well. I now need to return some data from a 3rd related table but not sure how to do this.

Here's my current SQL query

```
 select
    p.ID,
    p.post_title,
    p.post_name,
    max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as thumbnailID,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as Price,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as stockStatus,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sku'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as SKU,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sale_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as salePrice,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_regular_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as regularPrice,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'total_sales'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as totalSales

 from wp_posts p 
 join wp_postmeta pm
 on p.ID = pm.post_id

 where post_type = 'product'
 group by p.ID
```

I now need to get the value from the wp_postmeta table where the value of the _thumbnail_id in the wp_postmeta table matches the value of the post_id value in the wp_postmeta table AND the meta_key value = _wp_attached_file.

Here's some records from the wp_postmeta table:

[image]

The first record has a _thumbnail_id = 100. I now need to get the value of the record from the wp_postmeta table (same table) where the post_id = 100 and the meta_key = _wp_attached_file as shown here:

[image]

I know the thumbnail_id as that is returned as thumbnailID in my current query - just not sure how to then join this to the wp_postmeta table again.

Comment: why you need to join again..any idea?

Comment: Join your query and wp_postmeta. `select t.*, att.meta_value from (_your query_) as t left join wp_postmeta as att on att.post_id = t.thumbnail_id and att.meta_key ='_wp_attached_file'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked in the end - thanks for the help.

```
select
    p.ID,
    p.post_title,
    p.post_name,
    max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as thumbnailID,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as Price,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as stockStatus,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sku'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) as SKU,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_sale_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as salePrice,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_regular_price'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as regularPrice,
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'total_sales'  THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as totalSales,

    max(CASE WHEN  meta2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' THEN meta2.meta_value END ) as thumbnailURL



from wp_posts p 
join wp_postmeta pm
on p.ID = pm.post_id

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta meta2 
  ON meta2.post_id = pm.meta_value AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'



where post_type = 'product'


group by p.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta2 
WHERE meta2.post_id = max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'  THEN pm.meta_value END )
AND meta2.meta_key = _wp_attached_file
```

but it's ugly in my opinion.